# Python 3: Extract tar.gz archive without writing to disk

Tags: python, tar

Like the title said, is there a way to extract a tar.gz archive without writing a file to the disk (archive is downloaded from the internet). In bash or any other shell, I can just pipe the output of curl or wget to tar:

```
curl -L "https://somewebsite.com/file.tar.gz" | tar xzf -
```

Could I possibly do something like this in python as well?

edit: I'm using urllib to download data. I'm currently doing something like this to download and write to a file:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

filename = "/home/bob/file.tar.gz"
url      = "https://website.com/file.tar.gz"

file = open(filename, "wb")
file.write(urlopen(url).read())
file.close
```

Comment: os.system with that command line would be easiest. There's also the "tarfile" module in the standard library https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html

Comment: I have checked out the tarfile module and I can only see how to extract an archive that's already downloaded or present in the file sistem. So I guess I would have to use a the shell command then

Comment: No code here for me to correct, but note that the fileobj parameter can be an python object which implements read()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using help from kenny's comment, I did what I wanted to do by parsing the data i got from urlopen, use BytesIO, and use that as the fileobj argument for tarfile.open:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO

r = urlopen("https://url/file.tar.gz")
t = tarfile.open(name=None, fileobj=BytesIO(r.read()))
t.extractall("/somedirectory/")
t.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

without writing TAR file to disk, you could use python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to run shell commands for you:

```
import subprocess

# some params
shell_cmd = 'curl -L "https://somewebsite.com/file.tar.gz" | tar xzf -'
i_trust_this_string_cmd = True
throw_error_on_fail = True
timeout_after_seconds = 10 # or None
convert_output_from_bytes_to_string = True
#

# run shell as subprocesses to this one and get results
cp = subprocess.run(
    [shell_cmd],
    shell=i_trust_this_string_cmd,
    check=throw_error_on_fail,
    timeout=timeout_after_seconds,
    text=convert_output_from_bytes_to_string
)

#status_code = cp.returncode

try:
    cp.check_returncode() # triggers exceptions if errors occurred
    print(cp.stdout) # if you want to see the output (text in this case)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    print(cpe)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as te:
    print(te)
```

If you wanted more control, you could provide a PIPE for say STDOUT, STDERR  e.g.

```
with open('/tmp/stdout.txt', 'w+') as stdout:
    with open('/tmp/stderr.txt', 'w+') as stderr:
        cp = subprocess.run([...], stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
        ...
```